# Allure report generation fails with message ''allure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function..'

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io, allure, reporters

I am using Allure report for my WebDriverIO mocha test automation. Report generation was working fine however, it started showing below error while running 'allure generate allure-result' command.

> allure : The term 'allure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - allure genertae
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (allure:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException```

This is my package.json devDependencies

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.16.11",
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.13",
        "chromedriver": "^97.0.2",
        "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.6"
    },
```

What could be the reason for this failure and how to handle it?

Answer (score 7):

Run:

```
npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev
```

Resolved the issue for me.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways this could be rectified

The first method works reliably.

Run these 2 commands in Powershell to install scoop

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://get.scoop.sh | Invoke-Expression
```

now once that is done run other command which installs allure

```
scoop install allure
```

now check version of allure using `allure --version`

[image]

The second method is to check the environment variables and PATH for allure reports, to see if it is present or not